# Vue3 and Supabase when connecting via Remote device I get "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/ws' failed: "

Tags: postgresql, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, supabase

I am using a Nuxt3 server currently running in develop mode that uses a Supabase Database and when I try to connect to the server from a diffrent device then my localhost I get a constant error of "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/ws' failed: " in the develop console.

I want this error to stop because I have a diffrent problem and want to rule out this error as a source for problems.

So far I didnt really try much because I just dont know where to start. I guess that it has something to do with Supabases Postgres database, but I am quite new to Vue3 and Supabase so I dont know if a URL needs to be configured diffrently.

Appreciate it if someone with more knowlede could help me!

Update:
This is how the error looks on a remote device
[image]

And this is how it looks on the local device
[image]

For Nuxt my Package.json looks like this
[image]

And my nuxt.config.ts looks like this
[image]

Additional information that might be usefull:
I store the supabase url and key in a .env file and when I use supabase I do it with:

```
const user = useSupabaseUser()
const client = useSupabaseClient()
```

The error always occures when I try to access the website by using the Network URL provided by the `yarn dev` command. It happens on mobile devices aswell as other computers

Comment: How are you initializing your Supabase client in your Nuxt3 app? What Supabase URL and anon key are you passing it?

Comment: I store the url and key in a..env file and when i wamt to use supabase i uns client =useSupabaseClient or user=useSuperbaseUser

Comment: Thanks for that. And you say that you have Nuxt3 running in development mode, and you are trying to connect to it from a different device, but are you trying to connect from your phone or something? Also, how are you connecting from a different device if it's just running locally?

Comment: I supplied more info now in the question

Comment: Could you provide an example of `Network URL provided by the yarn dev`? Also, your Supabase URL is also local host?